# I can't import import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter after migration to spring-boot 2.6.7

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an application that uses Spring Boot 2.0.2. After I migrated to spring-boot 2.6.7, I can't import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter.

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.6.7.RELEASE/api/), this class is still in the new version of Spring Boot, and located in org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter, but I can not import this class.

I use that class to configure the following bean:

```java
@Bean
public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {
    return new RepositoryRestConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
            config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(RepositoryDetectionStrategy.RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED);
            config.setExposeRepositoryMethodsByDefault(false);
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TODO: Do we really need this dependency?-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.28.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.AM2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j
                </artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jmockit/jmockit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.212</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>webapp</finalName>
                <profiles>
                    <profile>local</profile>
                    <profile>prod</profile>
                    <profile>pg</profile>
                </profiles>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: What build tool are you using and what dependencies have you declared?

Comment: Hi @SpaceTrucker I use maven and I will share my pom above

Comment: What do you mean “can’t import”? What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and the correct answer appears to be: RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter has been deprecated and should be replaced with direct calls to RepositoryRestConfigurer.

Note my source for this information is the [deprecation list for version 3.1](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/3.1.7.RELEASE/deprecated-list.html) -- but I nonetheless applied this fix after updating to spring-boot 2.6.6 and it appears to have remedied the issue.

Comment: In general, the adapter classes aren’t required anymore since Java 8 supports default methods in interfaces.